# Guessing probability distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

The question is if probability of bomb hitting a target is 50% and 2 direct hits will destroy the target completely. How many bombs must be dropped to give a 99% chance or better of destroying the target completely?
I assume this question can be done using **negative binomial distribution** where favourable number of results is 2?
Am I right this is an example in my book and author used binomial distribution.
Please suggest if any other possible method is applicable?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you drop $n$ bombs, you *do not* destroy the target iff all the bombs miss or just one bomb hits the target. That happens with probability $\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{n}{2^n}$, hence you are looking for the smallest $n$ that grants
$$ \frac{n+1}{2^n}\leq \frac{1}{100}.$$
Such $n$ is $\color{red}{11}$.

Comment: Sir, you give the exact answer what the book says. But what is the intuition behind your solution or you used the same binomial distribution..

Comment: Sorry sir I get the method but how do you calculate the probability to be 1/2^n +n/2^n

Comment: How do you compute the probability that all the $n$ bombs miss? How do you compute the probability that all the bombs but one miss?

Comment: By using formula for binomial distribution for this ques.i.e.nC0(1/2^n)& nC1(1/2^n) Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: exactly. $\binom{n}{0}=1,\binom{n}{1}=n$.